# How do include left and right menu and main?

Tags: html, css

So i want to include a left and right menu with a main feed in the middle.
The problem is, the left and right menus seem to be scrolling along with the scroll bar.
I would like to have the main scrolling along with the scroll bar and the left and right menus to be stationary. 
How do i do this?

Comment: You'll have to show us the code

Comment: you've gotta give us more to go on than that. show some code & describe the problem a little more :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the css position value for your menus :

```
#menu-left { position : fixed }
#menu-right {position : fixed }
```

They'll keep on the same position on screen while page scrolls.